# insert columns to file with bash or alike

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Suppose I have a file like

```
1 3 44 5
2 23 1 44
```

and I would like to add two columns of 0s after the first two, to get

```
1 3 0 0 44 5
2 23 0 0 1 44
```

I could use something like

```
cat file|(
for ((i=0;i<nlines;i++))
do
   read l
   echo $(echo $l|cut -d" " -f -2) 0 0 $(echo $l|cut -d " " -f 3-)
done
) >output
```

where `nlines` is the known number of lines. But this happens to be extremely slow.

What is the way to do the job in a *fast* way?
Bash, awk or other linux command-line tools are ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk` you can do:

```sh
awk '{$3 = "0 0 " $3} 1' file

1 3 0 0 44 5
2 23 0 0 1 44
```

Or this `sed` would also work:

```sh
sed -i.bak -E 's/^(([^ ]+ +){2})/\10 0 /' file

cat file

1 3 0 0 44 5
2 23 0 0 1 44
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl is good for fast text manipulations. Here, you could do

```sh
perl -i.bak -lane 'splice @F, 2, 0, (0, 0); print join " ", @F' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` too:

```
sed -E 's/^([^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]*)(.*)$/\1 0 0\2/' file
```

Or `ruby`:

```
ruby -lane 'puts ($F[0..1]+["0"]*2+$F[2..]).join(" ")' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk '{$2=$2 " 0 0 "} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simply adding space and 2 zeros(separated by spaces) followed by space into 2nd field itself and printing the current line.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i 's/\S\+/& 0 0/2' file
```

Replace the 2nd column by itself and append  `0 0`.